# Facebook Debugger Error: Meta Tags In Body

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags, meta

When I check my website in the Facebook Debugger, I get this error:

> Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Meta Tags In Body Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. >This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse >tree.
>   Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

I believe this error also causes all other tags to become invalid.

I have been trying for many hours to locate the meta tags in the body, and have looked at the source, but I'm having trouble finding any in the body. I have tested it with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool, but it doesn't show any errors. It shows 3 identical versions of the same organization made through json, itemprop, and property (is that bad?).

I have looked at other stackoverflow questions about it, and they seem to get the help by letting others look at their homepage sources.

I know that my meta tags aren't very tidy or optimized, but right now I really need to fix this error. I appreciate any keen observations that can solve it!

**Post comments:**

Great tool for identifying and fixing HTML errors: http://validator.w3.org/
Another HTML improving tool with live response: http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

Comment: Your homepage has several HTML errors (you have, for example, two `html` elements), which you would ideally fix beforehand. And you can easily find `meta` elements in the `body` with a simple Ctrl+f search (some are allowed, some not). Anyway, to make this question on-topic, you have to include in your question the minimal (!) code that gives this error.

Comment: @unor By two html elements, do you mean <!doctype html> and
<html lang="en" class="no-js">? Do you know how I could combine them? I have used the search function, but I haven't found any metas outside <head></head>. As for the code, I could post the source, but it's fairly long, so I'm not sure if I should. I have provided the link to the website with the issues.

Comment: (1) You should not provide the full code, but the minimal code (this means: ideally only what is giving the error, nothing else; so remove anything not related to the error in question). The problem with links is that they might go 404, or that you are changing the markup -- then this question is of no use to anyone else anymore. (2) Just search for the opening tag `<html` -- leaving comment aside, you have two `html` elements: `<html lang="en" class="no-js">` and `<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" />`.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://wildifyme.com/

Comment: @unor Thanks, I didn't realize it until now! I added it to the html on the beginning of the page, and commented the old one out. Sharing and several meta tags seem to work now, but I still get the meta tags in the body error with the Facebook debug tool. Also, I'm sorry, but I'm not really sure where the minimal code starts and end in this case...

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the link to the w3c validator! Yeah, I see that my website has some issues. The three worst errors seem to be these:

Error Line 368, Column 7: Stray end tag head. </head>

Error Line 375, Column 93: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open. …ifyme-an-online-store-where-shopping-and-charity-meets" class="template-index">

Error Line 375, Column 93: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored. …ifyme-an-online-store-where-shopping-and-charity-meets" class="template-index">

How can I fix a "Stray end tag head"?

Comment: “Stray end tag head” is what you get when the `head` element was closed before already; and that doesn’t have to be explicitly, but can also happen implicitly when you have an element there that is not allowed to be part of `head`. Many times errors you will see “further down” are caused by stuff higher up. Therefor, the best recommendation IMHO is, start fixing errors from the top.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, there was a div and some typos that caused the errors in the head. Thank you for sharing that great validator tool! I had no idea I had so many problems with the website, but the critical ones have been removed now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` must be put before `<html>`, line 68 usless comments, line 103 is wrong too.

EDIT

To beautify your code you can use http://www.dirtymarkup.com/

Comment: Hello, ZwartyZ, I added <!doctype html> to the top now, but still get the error. As for line 68 and 103, in the source I assume, I agree that 
<!-- --------------------------> is useless, but I haven't gotten so far as to making the source tidy, unfortunately. And for line 103, I thought 
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" /> would be important as it was generated with the Google's snippet tool.

Comment: On link 103 the <html itemscope itemtype="schema.org/Organization"; /> is wrong because there can't be more then an html tag for each page, i suggest to try to insert itemscope and itemtype="..." in the html at the beginning of your page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that! I added it to the html at the beginning now. The sharing and several meta tags seem to work now, but I still get the meta tags in the body error.

Comment: There are a lot more errors then i expect, first you have to delete the usless comment i found before, second, line 2699 the div and his content must be in the body tag and not after it. I'm searching for other errors. I didn't found any meta tag in your body element anyways.

Comment: Meta charset tag have to be the first tag after opening the head element and title tag should follow it.

Comment: Anyways i suggest too to use the W3 validator to find the errors because there are really many many of them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Yeah, I had honestly no idea how bad it really was. I put the div inside the body tag, and put the charset tag in the beginning of the <head>. Now I suspect that I have some code inside the head that disables it before </head>, giving me a new error. I also have an error with the opening <body> tag too. Not sure if it matters, but the website is a Shopify site.

Comment: This is what I have in the theme.liquid file:
<body id="{{ page_title | handle }}" class="{% if customer %}customer-logged-in {% endif %}template-{{ template | replace: '.', ' ' | truncatewords: 1, '' | handle }}">

In the source, it looks like: 
<body id="wildifyme-an-online-store-where-shopping-and-charity-meets" class="template-index">

Comment: I think that the error is in the head but that it also affects the body, unfortunately i really have no idea about where it could be

Comment: hm , maybe I found it, try to delete the div at line 342 and see what happen

Comment: Well, I found a set of 3 }}} on this line:   {{ 'timber.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}, and by removing some redundant meta tags, I don't get any errors with the Facebook Debug Tool, but I get a serious error with the head:

Comment: 3.Error: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.

From line 339, column 1; to line 339, column 18

->↩  ↩↩  ↩<div id="fb-root"></div>
Content model for element head:If the document is an iframe srcdoc document or if title information is available from a higher-level protocol: Zero or more elements of metadata content, of which no more than one is a title element and no more than one is a base element.Otherwise: One or more elements of metadata content, of which exactly one is a title element and no more than one is a base element.

Comment: The problem is that the tag `<title></title>` in the head is missing

Comment: I dont know what to say about the <div id="fb-root"></div>, i tried to remove it and i dont get errors anymore, probably because it close the head tag implicitly and so it cause an error.

Comment: I tried to remove it too, and it seems like it didn't have any effect on Facebook's presence on the website, thanks! Now there are some errors on the body part, but they aren't as critical as the ones in the head! Thank you for all the help - I would surely not be able to fix it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of syntax problems. The head of your document looks like this:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
```

The doctype should be before the `<html>` tag, not after. Also, you have a bunch of invalid elements, such as `<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" />`.

Check out the [W3 Validator's take on your page](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwildifyme.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices). There are many, many issues that you need to fix.

Comment: Hello, Ed, thanks for the tips. I have fixed those two problems now, and others, but you are right about me having lots of issues with the website. I'm trying to fix all the issues now with the validator.

Comment: I would like to, but ZwartyZ helped me a bit more in detail, so I gave him the accepted answer. But thank you for your contribution!